# want to validating form for contact in php using Javascript only

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
This  is my Javascript code
playing-cards-quote.php

function MM_validateForm()
        { //v4.0
          if (document.getElementById)
          {
            var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
            for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) 
            { 
        test = args[i+2];
        val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
              if (val)
                  {
                      nm = val.name;
                      if ((val=val.value)!="")
                          {
                if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1)
                    {
                        p=val.indexOf('@');
                  if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1))
                      errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
                } 
                else 
                    if (test!='R')
                        {
                            num = parseFloat(val);
                  if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
                  if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) 
                  {
                      p=test.indexOf(':');
                    min=test.substring(8,p); 
                    max=test.substring(p+1);
                    if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
              }
              } 
              } 
              else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n';
              }
            } 
            if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
            document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
        }
        }



This is my HTMl code name on the same page
playing-cards-quote.php 


                <h2>Your Contact Information :</h2>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="fname" type="text" id="fname"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Last  Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input class="form-control" name="lname"  type="text" id="lname" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Email Id</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" id="email"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">(Please type in a correct email address , as the quotes will be forwarded there)</div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Telephone Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="telno" type="text" id="telno"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">( Do not enter space)
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Mobile Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="mobileno" type="text" id="mobileno"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">&nbsp;Company Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="cname" type="text" id="cname"  /></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><input class="form-control" name="address" type="text" id="address"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Zip Code :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="zipcode" type="text" id="zipcode" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div> 
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="city" type="text" id="city"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="state" type="text" id="state"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Country</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="country" type="text" id="country"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">&nbsp;Fax</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="fax" type="text" id="fax"  />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Captcha</label>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <?php echo '<img src="captcha.php" alt="captcha">'; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="captcha"/></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn1" name="submit" id="send">
            </center>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>


This is my thank-you.php code
<?php
    $message = "<table border='1'>";
    $message .= "<tr>
    <th>Plastic Coated Paper</th>
    <td>".($_POST['plastic_coated_paper'] == 'Select Paper' ? 'NA' : $_POST['plastic_coated_paper'])."</td>
    <th>100% Pure Plastic</th>
    <td>".($_POST['pure_plastic'] == 'Select Plastic' ? 'NA' : $_POST['pure_plastic'])."</td>
    </tr>"; 
    $message .= "<tr>
    <th>Quantity (Number of decks)</th>
    <td>".$_POST['quantity']."</td><th>Size Specifications</th><td>".$_POST['size_specifications']."</td>
    </tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Enter your Custom Size and Shape</th><td>".($_POST['custom_size_shape'] == '' ? 'NA' :$_POST['custom_size_shape']).
                "</td><th>Number of cards per deck</th><td>".($_POST['cards_per_deck'] == '' ? 'NA' : $_POST['cards_per_deck'])."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Playing Card Faces</th><td>".($_POST['playing_card_faces'] == 'Select Faces' ? 'NA' : $_POST['playing_card_faces']).
                "</td><th>Colors to be printed on Front</th><td>".($_POST['colors_to_be_printed_on_front'] == 'Select Color' ? 'NA' : $_POST['colors_to_be_printed_on_front'])."</td></tr>";    
    $message .= "<tr><th>Colors to be printed on Back</th><td>".($_POST['colors_to_be_printed_on_back'] == 'Select Color' ? 'NA' : $_POST['colors_to_be_printed_on_back']).
                "</td><th>Panton Special Color Requirement</th><td>".($_POST['panton_special_color_requirement'] == '' ? 'NA' : $_POST['panton_special_color_requirement'])."</td></tr>";   
    $message .= "<tr><th>Wrapping</th><td>".($_POST['wrapping'] == 'Select Wrapping Options' ? 'NA' : $_POST['wrapping']).
                "</td><th>Coating Finish</th><td>".($_POST['coating_finish'] == 'Select Coating' ? 'NA' : $_POST['coating_finish'])."</td></tr>";   
    $message .= "<tr><th>Gold Foil Options</th><td>".(($_POST['gold_foil_option'] != 'Gold / Silver Printing' && $_POST['gold_foil_option1'] != 'Gold Foil Stamping' ) ? 'NA' : $_POST['gold_foil_option'].'<br/>'.$_POST['gold_foil_option1']).
                "</td><th>Feel Of The Cards</th><td>".(($_POST['feel_of_card'] != 'Non Embossed/Smooth Finished' && $_POST['feel_of_card1'] != 'Embossed/Linen Finished/Textured Cards') ? 'NA' : $_POST['feel_of_card'].$_POST['feel_of_card1'])."</td></tr>"; 
    $message .= "<tr><th>Leather Cases</th><td>".($_POST['leather_cases'] == 'Select Leather Cases' ? 'NA' : $_POST['leather_cases']).
                "</td><th>Instruction Sheet Paper</td><td>".($_POST['instruction_sheet_paper'] == 'Select Instruction Sheet Paper' ? 'NA' : $_POST['instruction_sheet_paper'])."</th></tr>";    
    $message .= "<tr><th>Instruction Sheet Printing Options</th><td>".($_POST['instruction_sheet_printing_options'] == 'Select Printing Options' ? 'NA' : $_POST['instruction_sheet_printing_options']).
                "</td><th>No. of colors for the instruction sheet</th><td>".($_POST['no_of_colors_for_instruction_sheet'] == 'Select Instruction Sheet Color' ? 'NA' : $_POST['no_of_colors_for_instruction_sheet'])."</td></tr>";  
    $message .= "<tr><th>Packaging</th><td>".($_POST['packaging'] == 'Select Packaging' ? 'NA' : $_POST['packaging']).
                "</td><th>Delivery Time</th><td>".($_POST['delivery_time'] == 'Select Delivery Time' ? 'NA' : $_POST['delivery_time'])."</td></tr>";    
    $message .= "<tr><th>Display Pack Option</th><td>".($_POST['display_pack_option'] == 'Select Display Pack Option' ? 'NA' : $_POST['display_pack_option']).
                "</td><th>Mode of Delivery</th><td>".( $_POST['mode_of_delivery'] == 'Select Mode of Delivery' ? 'NA' : $_POST['mode_of_delivery'])."</td></tr>";   
    $message .= "<tr><th>Custom Packaging Enter Your Details</th><td colspan=3>".($_POST['details'] == '' ? 'NA' : $_POST['details'])."</td></tr>"; 
    $message .= "<tr><th>First Name</th><td>".$_POST['fname']."</td><th>Last Name</th><td>".$_POST['lname']."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Email</th><td>".$_POST['email']."</td><th>Telephone number</th><td>".$_POST['telno']."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Company Name</th><td>".$_POST['cname']."</td><th>Mobile number</th><td>".$_POST['mobileno']."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Address</th><td>".$_POST['address']."</td><th>City</th><td>".$_POST['city']."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Zip Code</th><td>".$_POST['zipcode']."</td><th>State</th><td>".$_POST['state']."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><th>Country</th><td>".$_POST['country']."</td><th>Fax</th><td>".($_POST['fax'] == '' ? 'NA' : $_POST['fax'])."</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<table>";
    $subject = "Order Detail Summary of alltypesofplayingcards.com";
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

    //Mail for TMCards
    $mail_tmcards = new PHPMailer();
    $mail_tmcards->IsSMTP();  // set mailer to use SMTP 
    $mail_tmcards->Host = "pro.turbo-smtp.com";       //192.168.1.10 localhost // specify main and backup server
    $mail_tmcards->SMTPAuth = true;           // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail_tmcards->Username   = "ashok@tmcards.com"; // SMTP account username example
    $mail_tmcards->Password   = "89HHRu738nWqdd"; 
    $mail_tmcards->From = $_POST['email'];
    $mail_tmcards->FromName = $_POST['fname']. " ".$_POST['lname'];
    $mail_tmcards->AddAddress('yogesh@tmcards.com');

    //$mail_user->AddReplyTo($fromemail, 'TMCARDS DOT COM Crm System');
    //$mail_user->ConfirmReadingTo='sales@tmcards.com';
    $mail_tmcards->IsHTML(true);
    $mail_tmcards->Subject=$subject;
    $mail_tmcards->Body=$message;   
    if(!$mail_tmcards->Send())
    {
       echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
       echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail_tmcards->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
    }
?>
```

I want to validate my form in PHP form using JavaScript. HTML form is Ok but I don't want to change the JavaScript code and more importantly, I want to validate form in PHP using PHP function. The value which I will insert in the textbox should submit it to the server.

Comment: Can you tell us where exactly you are facing the problem?

Comment: I just want to do from validation in php

Comment: Ok. So what exactly problem you are facing in validation. Ex: if the field is ```fname``` then you just need to make sure it shouldn't be empty. For that just compare the incoming data with an empty string. Ex.```if($_GET['fname']=='')``` . Similarly, you've to do for rest of data elements.

Comment: sir what is $message and what is the use of that $message?

Comment: ```$message``` is a PHP variable. whenever you use ```$``` symbol in front of any word that's called as a PHP variable. Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp

Comment: why my php form validation is given in function MM_validateForm() ?

Comment: Whether MM_validateForm() function logic contains form php validation?

Comment: Ok. From your questions, I feel like you've might've copy pasted all these codes from somewhere & you can't able to understand what's it's doing. But, explaining everything with codes at here is difficult for me. 

Normally for such situation, one need to apply validation at 2 places. One is at Client-side using JavaScript & another one is at Server side by using PHP.  So, If any user will bypass any validation at client side system will catch that in server side.  

From your question The function ```MM_validateForm()```  is client side code in Javascript.

Comment: thanks for helping me dude .......i m new to PHP language that why it difficult to understand code

Comment: No Problem. It's a normal situation for every beginner. But, my advice will be before diving to code directly.. first get your hand dirty about HTML + PHP + Javascript. That'll help you to tackle your problem more efficiently.

Comment: Just to bolt onto what @mi6crazyheart is saying, I recommend you check out either codecademy.com or freecodecamp.com or maybe both for learning the basics of HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP. You can also learn other languages too, but I recommend sticking to just a couple at first.